# A multi-purpose word

Tags: riddle, word

I can be defining,
But I don't give much away.
I can be pretty good,
Except when I'm nasty.
I'm never at the extremes,
But you'll find me with a switch at the end.

**Question:** What word am I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

> MEAN

I can be defining

> *mean* can be used to describe a meaning of sth i.e. define its *meaning*. Also *fussy* is one possible use of *mean*.

But I don't give much away.

> By calculating the average you don't get much other information besides that. Also *mean* can be used for people who don't like sharing money/things.

I can be pretty good,

> It can be good (or not :P) when talking about grades/marks. **Edit:** colloquial for *excellent*

Except when I'm nasty.

> mean can also mean *nasty*

I'm never at the extremes,

> Due to the way of how you calculate an *average* (math.) it never can be at the extremes (given there is more than one value :p )

But you'll find me with a switch at the end.

> Oh hell..... AMEN :D

Comment: Can you explain how your word would fit with each line of the riddle?

Comment: Will do that :)

Comment: You've got the right word. Your second sentence for the second line of the riddle is the intended sense of the word and lines 4 and 5 have been interpreted correctly. Can you think how lines 1, 3 and 6 could fit better?

Comment: Good job pal. I like it :)

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking

> Sick

I can be defining,

> Sick can be used as an adjective, or like a defining part in someones life. ("Getting sick was a defining point in Rick's life, now he doesn't smoke anymore")

But I don't give much away.

> Sick is a very broad term to describe something, illness or action

I can be pretty good,

> Can be used in a good way! ("That was a sick 720 Gazelle Flip bro!")

Except when I'm nasty.

> Describing yourself or someone else. ("I just got sick" or "Jenny is sick today")

I'm never at the extremes,

> Normally sick isn't used as a term to describe a terminal illness or to describe something astonishing or breathtaking.

But you'll find me with a switch at the end

> CK Components is a well known manufacture of many different types of switches!

Comment: A few of those are a but more tenuous than the intended answer. I'm not relying on the name of any company.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be:

> riddle

Here's why:

---

I can be defining,

> A riddle should be defining and define some answer

But I don't give much away.

> Riddles normally don't give too many hints, otherwise it's not a good one

I can be pretty good,

> There are good and bad riddles(obviously)

Except when I'm nasty.

> Definition of "nasty" is "*very bad or unpleasant*", which is also an opposite of "good"

I'm never at the extremes,

> Can't find any decent explanation for this line (yet).

But you'll find me with a switch at the end.

> Once you know the answer you'll be like: "Aha! Now it makes sense!"

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking. However, for me for the Switch, since Riddle ends with E, there's a company (?) called E-Switch. Haha. Though, we're both stuck on the 'I'm never at the extremes'.

Comment: Nice try, but not what I'm looking for. I'm not relying on any company names.